# do not see the expected data within my ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a $scope variable `epochs` that loops through an array containing 3 items -

```
<div class="epoch" ng-repeat="epoch in epochs" ng-init="epochIndex = $index">
    <div class="epoch-time">
        <span class="epoch-header">{{epoch[epochIndex].epoch}} {{ epochIndex }}</span>
    </div>
```

Expected result : 
See the following divs in the template

```
<span class="epoch-header">Today 0</span>
<span class="epoch-header">Tommorow 1</span>
<span class="epoch-header">Thu, 11 Jan 2</span>
```

Actual result :

```
<span class="epoch-header">Today 0</span>
<span class="epoch-header">1</span>
<span class="epoch-header">2</span>
```

I can view the variable from the console and when I run the scope variable with each numerical key I can see the expected values - it just doesn't pass through to my template for the latter spans??

Can anyone suggest what is incorrect?

Comment: You have a typo, it should be `{{epochs[epochIndex].epoch}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean?

```
<div class="epoch" ng-repeat="epoch in epochs">
    <div class="epoch-time">
        <span class="epoch-header">{{epoch}} {{ $index }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do directly this:

```
<div class="epoch" ng-repeat="epoch in epochs">
 <div class="epoch-time">
    <span class="epoch-header">{{epoch}} {{$index}}</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong , **try this**

```
<div class="epoch" ng-repeat="epoch in epochs" ng-init="epochIndex = $index">
      <div class="epoch-time">
         <span class="epoch-header">{{epoch}} {{epochIndex}}</span>
      </div>
</div>
```